# tan и бесконечность

Tags: c++, математика

Может ли `tan` возвратить бесконечность? При каком значении? `pi/2` не возвращает бесконечность (из за погрешностей, наверно).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, `tan` не может вернуть бесконечность (`+Inf` или `-Inf`).

Из примечания к описанию `tan` в [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan):

> У функции есть полюса при `x = π(1/2 + n)`, однако существующие реализации чисел с плавающей точкой не могут точно представить π/2, поэтому аргумент никогда не попадает в полюс.

Comment: @JohnCena `n` - целое число, полюс - точка, где функция уходит в бесконечность.
P.S. Более точно, *полюс* - это изолированная особая точка голоморфной в проколотой окрестности этой точки функции, причём предел функции в этой точке существует и равен бесконечности.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, что нет.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan

> If a domain error occurs, an implementation-defined value is returned (NaN where supported)

Перевод: в случае выхода значения за рамки допустимого диапазона, возвращаемое значение зависит от реализации (NaN, если поддерживается)

Т.е. мы можем получить `NaN` (насколько я понимаю, это входит в 11-й стандарт), но не `inf`

Comment: Да, `tan(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())` возвращает `NaN`.

Comment: @kff, вы как-то перескочили с возвращаемого значения на операнд. Вычислите-ка tan(inf) при помощи математики, безо всякого c++! Получилось? Потому и NaN! И совсем другое дело - atan(infinity)!

Comment: @kff, читаю: VladD говорит, что на вход даем pi/2 - на выходе не infinity. Вы и andy.37 рассуждаете, что будет, если не выполнить предусловие, ну, полная ерунда и будет, не существует предела $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infinity} \tan{x} .

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к имеющимся правильным ответам: Вот значение, на котором `tan` перепрыгивает через бесконечность: http://ideone.com/gfyJoD

```
double x = 1.57079632679489666901; // около PI/2
double y = nextafter(x, numeric_limits<double>::max()); // в точности следующее
cout << fixed << tan(x) << endl; // 16331239353195370.000000
cout << fixed << tan(y) << endl; // -6218431163823738.000000
```

(разумеется, данное значение имеет смысл лишь в данной версии рантайма, так что никаких гарантий)

---

Почему же разработчики стандарта решили никогда реально не возвращать бесконечность?

Причин здесь две:

1. Точное значение π/2 + *n* · π не представимо в виде числа типа `double` (т. к. π иррационально). Даже если тангенс аргумента больше максимального значения `double`, всё равно округление вниз даст лучшее приближение, чем *бесконечная* ошибка при округлении до бесконечности!
2. Если даже и возвращать значение «бесконечность», неясно, какую именно (положительную или отрицательную) нужно возвращать. У `double` нету «просто бесконечности».

Comment: Влад, по 2-му пункту можно доп. вопрос? А какую бесконечность возвращает `numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`?

Comment: @andy.37: Согласно [вот этому](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity), положительную.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `tan`, несмотря на наличие тега [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) в вопросе, относится к функциям из библиотеки `C`. Поэтому и ответ на вопросе логичнее искать в сишном Стандарте.

И вот что говорит по этому поводу `C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999)` **7.12.4.7**:

> The **tan** functions
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <math.h> 
> double tan(double x); 
> float tanf(float x); 
> long double tanl(long double x);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The **tan** functions return the tangent of **x** (measured in
>   radians).
>
> **Returns**
>
> The **tan** functions return tan **x**.

Т.е. пока никакой ясности про бесконечность нет. Просто сказано, что функция возвращает тангенс аргумента, заданного в радианах.

Однако далее в приложении `F`, а точнее в п. `F.9.1.7` описаны особые случаи:

> **tan**(±0) returns ±0.
>
> **tan**(±∞) returns a NaN and raises the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception.

Из чего можно сделать вывод, что функция `tan` не возвращает ∞. Но может вернуть `NaN` для ∞ значения аргумента.

Другие функции, например **log10** для нулевого аргумента, возвращают ∞.